# How to access all documents on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, pdf

I am writing app that requires a user to select a document (PDF, DOC, image ETC) from a list of documents stored locally. How do I get about accessing such a dialog? That is do I write something that can populate a tableview or is there some pre-existing dialog that can be used?

Thank you and I hope I am making sense.

Comment: All documents on an iOS device or just those within your app's document directory?

Comment: It is a faxing application so if you need to fax any document, you just select any document on your iOS device. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement your own dialog, typically as a subclass of `UITableViewController`, there is no built-in UI for selecting files.